# Error calculating the actual iframe height

Tags: javascript

Here is my function. and in `onload` event handler I am trying to calculate the `scrollHeight` of `iframe`.
But I am getting only error messages. Can some one please help?

```
function showHBewertung(W3CElement, objCode) {
       var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
           iframe.className = "bewertung_iframe"  
           iframe.src = "http://example.com?giatacode="+objCode;
           W3CElement.appendChild(iframe);  

           iframe.onload = function() {
              var height=iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
              iframe.style.cssText = "width:100%;height:" + height + "px";
           }

    }
```

Comment: What do the error messages say in detail?

Comment: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: You can't access the contents of `iframe` when it's outside your domain for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the document if it is on the *same domain* (and using the same port and protocol) as the parent page. That is, to access the `http://example.com/` iframe document your iframe must be on a `http://example.com/` page. If you do that, you can access the iframe document's `scrollHeight` with `iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight`:

```
function showHBewertung(W3CElement, objCode) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.className = "bewertung_iframe";
    iframe.src = "http://example.com?giatacode="+objCode;
    W3CElement.appendChild(iframe);  
    iframe.onload = function () {
        var height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
        iframe.style.cssText = "width:100%;height:" + height + "px";
    };
}
```